# Dynamixel Controller Problems

Tags: ros, dynamixel, dynamixel-controller, ax12

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am running the AX-12 servo with the Dynamixel_controller package. I can successfully initialize the servo following the tutorial found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus). When I attempt to start the controller it produces the follwoing

```
 ... logging to /home/tyler/.ros/log/1427d53c-25e6-11e1-8030-00216a81ee0a/roslaunch ubuntu-31628.log
 Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

 started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:46229/

 SUMMARY
 ========

 PARAMETERS
  * /tilt_controller/joint_speed
  * /rosdistro
  * /tilt_controller/motor/init
  * /tilt_controller/motor/max
  * /tilt_controller/joint_name
  * /rosversion
  * /tilt_controller/motor/min
  * /tilt_controller/controller/package
  * /tilt_controller/motor/id
  * /tilt_controller/controller/module
  * /tilt_controller/controller/type

  NODES
   /
     tilt_controller_spawner (dynamixel_controllers/controller_spawner.py)

 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

 core service [/rosout] found
 process[tilt_controller_spawner-1]: started with pid [31646]
 [INFO] [WallTime: 1323822107.421650] /dev/ttyUSB0 controller_spawner: waiting for      controller_manager None to startup in global namespace...
```

I'm not sure why the controller_manager name is None and why it hangs up at this point. The tutorial I am following for this step can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/CreatingJointPositionController).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12336/dynamixel-controller-problems/) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the tutorials might be a bit outdated. Here what you need to do get going:

1. First we need to launch the controller manager node that will keep track of all loaded controllers (it also lets you stop, start and restart controllers). You can look at the example launch file in [dynamixel_tutorials](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/dynamixel_motor/tags/electric/dynamixel_tutorials/launch/controller_manager.launch) package. Make sure to set the correct min and max motor ids. Let's leave it running in a terminal window and proceed to the next step.
2. Define joint controllers. Look at the [dynamixel_tutorials](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/dynamixel_motor/tags/electric/dynamixel_tutorials/config/dynamixel_joint_controllers.yaml) example joint configuration.
3. Now open another terminal window and launch your joint controller. An example launch file is again in [dynamixel_tutorials](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/dynamixel_motor/tags/electric/dynamixel_tutorials/launch/controller_spawner.launch) package. Make sure that the manager command line argument is the same as the namespace parameter of a controller manager launched earlier (dxl_manager in this example). Same goes for the port command line argument, it should match the name given in the controller manager parameters (pan_tilt_port in this example).

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1